# How to create dropdown menu in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on Bootstrap template to create site similar to this one https://casper.com/ 
I want to know how to create dropdown menu like Shop/About/Reviews when you click the menu slides down panel with sub menu.

This is not a commercial project I just recreating this casper.com site to learn how to build website with Bootstrap.

Thanks

Comment: You can get a lot of examples here : http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/k04cujnj/